# Did I understand the definition of "gross primary production" correctly?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis, plant-anatomy

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_production#Gross_primary_production_and_net_primary_production)

> Gross primary production (GPP) is the amount of chemical energy as biomass that primary producers create in a given amount of time.

So if a plant creates 6g of biomass in 1 second for example, then the amount of chemical energy stored in the 6g increase in weight is the GPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you more or less got it!

If you have only 3 primary producers (say 3 plants) in a given ecosystem.

- Plant A produces 2g of organic carbon per second
- Plant B produces 5g of organic carbon per second
- Plant C produces 1g of organic carbon per second

, then the GPP is 8g per second.

This produced organic carbon can be in the form of leaves, root or whatever tissue these plants are growing.

Note: the numbers chosen are irealistic both in terms of production per second and in terms of number of plants in an ecosystem.

> gC (grams of carbon assimilated) m-2 (m squared) year-1", what is meant by "grams of carbon assimilated" ?

The whole point of primary producers is to fix carbon. That is to take inorganic carbon (such as $CO_2$) and make it organic (such as $C_6H_{12}O_6$ aka glucose). This is why we are typically particularly interested in carbon and not so much in water.

For more info, you should have a look at an intro course to respiration and calvin cycle.

Note that if you remove water from an organism you are roughly speaking left with 75% of carbon, 10% of Nitrogen and the rest made of different elements.

Comment: alright thanks,,, and when we say that the GPP is measured in "gC (grams of carbon assimilated) m-2 (m squared) year-1", what is meant by "grams of carbon assimilated" ? i quoted this from my book and i dont know what they mean by that.

Comment: Okay so if a plant makes for example 100g of organic product in one second then the mass of carbon in this 100g is the GPP in gC per second , right ?

Comment: wait what did you edit yesterday ? i cant see the difference. Can you please answer my last comment ?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Note however, that when you read a paper you want to make sure that they really measure the mass of carbon and not just the dry mass or the energy freed from combustion as many authors may use proxies.